# using a string in javascript from a template.html

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering how I can assign a string from template.html to a javascript variable. I'm using a php code that transforms rss to html. It replaces strings in a template.html in order to display information. I want to assign these replaced strings in javascirpt. Here my codes:

My template.html

```
 <TABLE width="100%">
        ~~~BeginItemsRecord~~~
        <TR>
            <TD>
                 ~~~ItemPubShortTime~~~
            </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>
                <B>~~~ItemTitle~~~</B>
            </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>
                <BR>
            </TD>
        </TR>
        ~~~EndItemsRecord~~~
    </TABLE>
```

When I run my program, for example instead of ~~~ItemPubShortTime~~~ you see time like 10.16AM. I want to assign 10.16 AM to a javascript variable in this file.

My script looks like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
var sglm=new Array();
sglm[0]= 'Hello World';

</script>
```

I want to put 10.16AM instead of 'Hello World'. I hope it is clear. Thank you.

Comment: This depends on what exactly you want. If a string is enough just write `sglm[0] = '~~~~ItemPubShortTime~~'`. If you need a real date, you have to convert the time to a real date first.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the JavaScript in the template as well, then assign it same way via the PHP code e.g.

```
   sglm[0]= '~~~ItemPubShortTime~~~';
```

Then it will be replaced along with the HTML.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. It is not displaying the time, it shows ~~~ItemPubShortTime~~~

Comment: Did you place the JS inside `template.html`?

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
<TD id="theId">~~~ItemPubShortTime~~~</TD>

<script language="javascript">
var sglm=new Array();
sglm[0]= document.getElementById("theId").textContent;

</script>
```

Comment: Why? He has the time already. No need to retrieve it from them DOM-Element. He can set it directly.

Comment: if you have a better solution, why didn't you answer instead of leaving a comment?

Comment: I did - read my comment to his question... Nonetheless am I not allowed to state that I find your answer unnecessarily complicated?

Comment: A comment is not an answer! answer his question as a "real answer" than he will validate it and he won't take care about my answer.

Comment: A comment may as well be a valid answer as an "answer" is. (Quite often the comments are even the better answers) Why should I post another answer if he hasn't commented on one of these yet especially when Shadow Wizards answer is similar to mine. No reason to be upset, your answer is perfectly valid. Just relax.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a loop over the td fields and write the textContent in the Array,

```
var sglm = [];
for (var i = 0, ilen = document.getElementsByTagName("TD").length; i < ilen; i++ ) {
    sglm.push(document.getElementsByTagName("TD")[i].textContent);
}
console.log(sglm[0]); //~~~ItemPubShortTime~~~​​​
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spuCk/)

If you don't have a console replace `console.log`with an `alert` or sth